# Lose data of local MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, iterm2

My scenario is that I use a local DB and I always keep it running. An hour ago, I upgraded iTerm2 and all opened windows/tabs closed. After I restart iTerm2, I found that **mongod** is still running, so I use `kill $(pidof mongod)` and restart with `mongod --dbpath ./db`. However, most data I inserted has disappeared. I have checked **.zsh_history** to confirm that I am using the same db folder. I have also checked all **mongod.lock** address on my computer to see other DB folders, and none of them stores my latest data. I have seen **mongo.log** and the commands I used to query new data was still there. Therefore, how can I find my lost data? Thanks.

P.S. This situation happened last month when my mac was forced to shut down because of low battery. It happens again so I ask and want to know why it happens and what I can do.

Comment: Remember that message which came up every time you launched a mongo shell ( or you probably didn't because you're using Robo 3T or some other GUI ) *"**WARNING**: Access control is not enabled for the database."*. Well that was there to tell you something. If you did not enable authentication and authorization ( `--auth` for `mongod` ) then basically **anything** can happen. If you have backups then use them. Also It's your "development" machine, so you really should not care.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for this valuable information. But I still want to know what I can deal with this case because it can save me much time rather than I reconstruct all data from the beginning.

Comment: Maybe you do want that. But this really does not have anything to do with programming other than usage of a tool. And as a "programmer" then you really should not have had any data present that you could not afford to loose. So if you are not actually a programmer, then you're asking on the wrong site. Even if you are, then asking about data recovery really has nothing to do with said "programming task". So this really **is not a question for this site**. You can A. Just move on B. Go ask on superuser.com or somewhere else about attempting to recover data simply in result of your "power off".

Comment: Furthermore, you're making a "presumption" that you *"..lost data[sic] ... when my mac was forced to shut down ..."*. Most likely that is not when things happened. As a "database" MongoDB would "periodically" flush data to disk whilst keeping a preference to make changes in memory. But that "periodic" interval is one minute at most. So unless you were right in the middle of a big bulk load of data, then in all likelihood all stateful changes have been written to disk. However as I have said, your database **was not secured** and as such this is the most likely point why data is missing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Probably it's because I didn't realise that what scope programming task can cover and I should ask this question to other sites. I agree with you that when it is not secured then no one can promise why data is missing.

Comment: After surveyed, I realised that the journaling was opened because the log in wiredTiger was not empty. (Through command `mongo --eval "db.serverStatus()"`) But I still can't find my data. Another possible reason is that it's a disk-level data corruption, so I tried `mongod --dbpath ./db --repair`, but it doesn't work.